# How can I compare the getchar() input with the previous input in getchar()?

Tags: c

Im trying to compare two inputs (or more) that the user insert. 
Im using getchar() function for it but it doesnt seem to work...
I need to first check wether its letter (in english) and if there are not 2 (or more) uppercase or lowercase letters in a row. 
here is what I did:

```
Boolean CheckLetters() {
    char ch1, ch2;
    Boolean valid = TRUE, loop = TRUE;
    printf("\nPlease enter char. When you are done press Enter.\n");
    ch1 = getchar();
    while (getchar() != 10);
    if ((ch1>='A' && ch1<='Z') || (ch1>='a' && ch1<='z')) {
        return valid;
    }
    ch2 = ch1;
    printf("\nbdika1");
    ch1 = getchar();
    while (getchar() != 10);
    while (loop)
    {
        if (ch1 != 10) {
            if (((ch1 >= 'A' && ch1 <= 'Z') && (ch2 >= 'a' && ch2 <= 'z')) ||
                ((ch1 >= 'a' && ch1 <= 'z') && (ch2 >= 'A' && ch2 <= 'Z'))) {
                ch2 = ch1;
                printf("\nbdika2");
                ch1 = getchar();
                while (getchar() != 10);
            }
            else
            {
                valid = FALSE;
                loop = FALSE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            loop = FALSE;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

The value of valid is returned to another function and if its true the function prints "correct" and opposite if false..
Now somewhy it doesnt work well.. I cant figure out whats wrong, I insert ch2 the value that is inserted to ch1 by getchar() and recieving new one and checking it, but the value that is returned isn't the value that is suppose to be returned...

**EDIT:**

OK, this is how it goes.
I need to write a function that getting a string of chars from the user (without using array or string) and when the user press Enter key or Spacebar it will stop and prints "Correct" in this cases:

a) If the user entered 0 chars.

b) If the user entered 1 char, and that char is a letter.

c) If the string goes like this: AaAa or aBcD (uppercase and lowercase next to each other)

the function prints "Incorrect" in this cases:

a) A char that was entered isn't a letter

b) 2 (or more) uppercase/lowercase letters were next to each other

the "printf("bdika") (bdika means check in my languge) is just to check what "if" was true. 
now somewhy the code I wrote doesnt work. Please try to help me understand whats wrong there and which changed I can do.

**Note** The printing is done by another function which recieve True or False from the previous function. If it recieve true it prints "Correct" and otherwise "Incorrect".

Comment: Are you sure this loop  while (getchar() != 10); makes sense?

Comment: When the user ends to insert the chars he needs to press Enter and show the result. Tbh I have no idea why this line must be added after each getchar() line but thats what I've been told to do..

Comment: `getchar();` returns 1 of 257 different values.  Why does code store that result in a `char` which holds 256 different values.  Certainly `EOF` must be confused with a legitimate characters.

Comment: The checking for the value `10` is not portable, What you really want to be checking for is `\n` which will work correctly on any system.   The returned value from `getchar()` is a `int`  The type for `ch1` and `ch2` should be `int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- You should define `ch1` and `ch2` with type `int` as `getchar()` returns an `int` that can have all values of type `unsigned char` **plus** the special value `EOF`. Type `char` cannot hold all these values and checking for end of file cannot be done reliably with this type.
- You should use character constants instead of hard-coded numerical values: use `'\n'` instead of `10`...
- Always check for `EOF` when you loop until a given character is typed, otherwise the loop will run indefinitely at end of file.
- You do not handle the case where the user hits  directly at the prompt. The flushing loop should not run in this case. You can write a utility function for this to avoid duplicating the code.
- I am not sure why you return immediately when the user enters a letter. The logic is obscure and the goal is not stated clearly either.

**EDIT** You finally clarified the expected behavior for user entry: just read one character at a time and reset the return value is the character is incorrect (not a letter) or if you detect an incorrect sequence (same case).

Here is a modified stand alone version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int Boolean;
#define TRUE   1
#define FALSE  0

Boolean CheckLetters(void) {
    int valid = TRUE;  // input is correct by default
    int ch1, ch2;

    // to avoid leaving characters in the input stream, the loop
    // reads all characters typed by the user upto the <enter> key.
    // return FALSE if an invalid character or an invalid sequence
    // is detected.
    printf("\nPlease enter chars. When you are done press Enter.\n");
    for (ch1 = EOF;;) {
        ch2 = ch1;      // save previous character
        ch1 = getchar();
        if (ch1 == EOF || ch1 == '\n') {
            // end of line or end of file, return status
            return valid;
        }
        if (ch1 >= 'A' && ch1 <= 'Z') {
            // character is uppercase letter,
            // check if previous character if any is lowercase
            if (!(ch2 == EOF || (ch2 >= 'a' && ch2 <= 'z'))) {
                // invalid sequence, will return Incorrect status
                valid = FALSE;
            }
        } else
        if (ch1 >= 'a' && ch1 <= 'z') {
            // character is lowercase letter,
            // check if previous character if any is uppercase
            if (!(ch2 == EOF || (ch2 >= 'A' && ch2 <= 'Z'))) {
                // invalid sequence, will return Incorrect status
                valid = FALSE;
            }
        } else {
            // character is not a letter, Incorrect status
            valid = FALSE;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Boolean valid = CheckLetters();
    if (valid) {
        printf("Correct\n");
    } else {
        printf("Incorrect\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the user enter only 1 char, I need to check if it's a Latin letter and if it is, return true, so that's why I did that

Comment: @MatanBenishty: how is the user supposed to enter 2 characters? `X<enter>Y<enter>` or `XY<enter>` ?

Comment: Its like a string, but you are not allowed to use a string, so like the second option you mentioned, XY

Comment: @MatanBenishty: If you expect the user to type multiple characters on a line, you should read the user input with `fgets()` and analyse the line contents.  The current scheme reads multiple lines, discarding all but the first character on each line.

Comment: I see you used some kind of array, which is also forbbiden to use. I see that I wasn't clear in my question, so I'll update it and add all the notes.. also, could you please explain how can I use the fget() and why do I need to use it? if I write c=getchar(), I cant use the value that c recieved?

Comment: `fgets()` read a line into a buffer upto and including the newline `'\n'` if it fits into the buffer. You probably cannot use that or arrays because you have not studied them yet. I shall revert to getting bytes from the user with `getchar()`, but this assignment seems contorted and quite useless.

Comment: I updated the question with all the details and tasks. Im so sorry that Im driving you crazy hehe. But its been 6 days that Im trying ANYTHING to make it work, but it doesnt work

Comment: @MatanBenishty: I finally understood what you are supposed to do.  It is important to state the specifications clearly, and the logical steps flow from that quite simply.  Follow the steps in my latest update and check if it solves the problem.

Comment: I tested your code, but it also not working well.. It returned True (the print of the other function is correct) to any input, even empty string or invalid sequence

Comment: OK I found out whats the problem! Because that there is a menue before that activate the function when getting a char, it somehow gets in the getchar right away. So I added " while(getchar()!=32); " before the first c=getchar() and it works smooth.        BTW, what does the for(;;) stands for?

Comment: @MatanBenishty: `for(;;)` pronounced *for ever loop* is equivalent to `while(1)`, which some people write `while (true)`.  It is a `for` loop with no condition expression, therefore it loops forever, until it hits a `return` or a `break` statement.

Comment: In your calling code, you probably have a `scanf()` that leaves a pending newline in the stream buffer.  Add a `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {}` after the `scanf()`. I made the code stand alone with a minimal `main()` function so you can run tests.  This is what you should do to test small bits of functionality: boil down the problem to a small stand alone example and debug that.

Comment: I see what you did. Thank you so much man! You made everything so much clear to me (unlike my lousy lecturer). Stay tuned for some more questions 'cause the next assingment is already up :P